# Is there any way to save Red5 publish video locally in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios7, red5, live-streaming

I am using `Red 5 Pro` for Live Streaming in my iOS Application.

I am able to record video on my sftp server while publishing using `R5RecordTypeRecord`

```
[publish publish:liveStreamName type:R5RecordTypeRecord];
```

Is there anyway to record publishing video in document directory of iPhone same as it is recorded in server?

Comment: Do you mean local to the iOS device? I don't believe that's possible with the SDK.

Comment: Yes locally . If this is not possible is there any way around. Or I have to.contact red 5 team

Answer (score 1):

I came here with the same question and looking for an answer, which unfortunately I haven't. Anyway, for the record I found these two Q&A from Red5 team:

(From November 2015) https://github.com/red5pro/red5pro-android-app/issues/6

(From April 2016) https://red5pro.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/216704777-Saving-Streams-Locally-iOS-and-Android-

So, it seems that it has been in their ToDoList for at least 1-2 years. I couldn't find any more recent news, nor those R5VideoSource implementations they are talking about.